# Unable to create instance of class database.networkData.TufeeResponse(Network Response Handler DTO)

Tags: android, retrofit, proguard

**What I have changed**

> This app was working fine until I have upgrade agp to 8.0.2 and gradle version to 8.0.
> || Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Canary 8

**Full Error**

> *Unable to create instance of class database.networkData.TufeeResponse. Registering an InstanceCreator or a TypeAdapter for this type, or adding a
> no-args constructor may fix this problem.*

**Response Handler Data Class**

```
data class TufeeResponse<out T>(
@SerializedName("statusCode") val statusCode: Int = 0,
@SerializedName("message") val message: String? = null,
@SerializedName("data") val data: T? = null
) {
   val isSuccess : Boolean
       get() {
       return statusCode == 1
     }
}
```

**Api Call Impl**

```
@POST("fetchAdmin")
suspend fun syncAdmin(@Body jsonObject: JsonObject) : TufeeResponse<AdminDto>
```

**Client Build**

```
fun getClient(): Retrofit {
if (retrofit == null) {
    synchronized(RetrofitBuilder::class.java){
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(
                GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().setLenient().create())
            )
            .client(
                OkHttpClient
                    .Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .build())
            .build()
    }
}
return retrofit!!
```

**Progaurd Rules**

```
#ParametrizedType ClassCastException error fix
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class database.networkData.TufeeResponse
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.** { *; }
```